# Eclipse RAP RWT Theming

Tags: eclipse, osgi, theming

I have a question concerning RAP RWT Theming - skining or application style(theming) in Eclipse RAP can be done by extension to branding by applying our own CSS style, defining to which EntryPoint it should be applied.

My question is: 
I have main Workbench APP let say in bundle/plugin A. Before Workbench window is populated I am using JAAS Security (to secure access to my App, by puting correct user name+ pass in LoginDialog). JAAS Security is let say bundle/plugin B. When I apply branding to plugin A, this is even applied to plugin B (which has loginDialog window). If I make another branding - lets say i want to have different look for LoginDialog window & different for WorkbenchWindow, I make branding in plugin B (with different CSS style applied).

Behaviour is following: branding of plugin B is applied 1st, because LoginDialog from pluginB is called, then main app start from pluginA - but second branding is never applied (looks that 1st branding from plugin B override also branding from plugin A).

I would really appreciate some help, how to make different RWT theming for different parts of RAP application. Does anybody have some experience with this ?

Thank you in advance

Tomas Kramaric

Answer (score 0):

You can look on this page: [RAP Developer Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.help%2Fhelp%2Fhtml%2Frwt%2Ftheming.html)

I did another solution:

This Code is in the Plugin.xml of my Theme Plugin:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.themes">
  <theme
        file="theme/test/test.css"
        id="com.yourApplicationName.theme.test"
        name="Test Theme">
  </theme>
```

And this Code is in the Plugin.xml of my EntryWindow:

```
<extension
     id="mailapp.entrypoints"
     point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">

     <entrypoint
        applicationId="yourApplicationName"
        brandingId="yourApplicationName.testAPP.ui.branding.default"
        id="testAPP.entrypoint"
        path="/">
      </entrypoint>

      <entrypoint
        applicationId="yourApplicationName.testAPP"
        brandingId="yourApplicationName.theme.branding.test"
        id="test.entrypoint"
        path="/test">
      </entrypoint>

 </extension>
```

In Browser you have to type this to open your own theme: http://127.0.0.1:10080/testAPP/**test**